# Magento2 Product / Category URL not showing SEO Friendly

Tags: magento2.2, url-rewrite

I am facing issue with product URL. Please open link below http://new1.nufoot.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=GREEN+BAROQUE+BETSY+LOU+NUFOOT

So when you click on 1st product - GREEN BAROQUE BETSY LOU NUFOOT , it will take you to URL:- http://new1.nufoot.com/catalog/product/view/id/765/s/green-baroque-betsy-lou-nufoot-women/ , but when you click on 2nd product it will take you to seo friendly url - http://new1.nufoot.com/green-baroque-ballet-flats-nufoot.html

I have done, reindex, cache clean & flush. Also, I have updated the category from admin. but nothing makes it work.

Can anyone help me with this, please!

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This was due to the SEO Friendly URL has been not generated for your product ID 765.

You can check it by below query:

```
SELECT * FROM `url_rewrite` WHERE `target_path` LIKE '%catalog/product/view/id/765/%'
```

You can fixed it by below steps:

- Installed the regenurl extension
  https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls
- Regenerate the url only for that product id for store 1

> php bin/magento iazel:regenurl -s1 765

Answer (score 0):

use this module that will be helpful for you
https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites